VS 2022 Cannot running emulator for API 34 / 35
My VS 2022 cannot start any emulator above API 33 (such as 34, 35). Anything below API 34 working fine.

API 34 Emulator show only blank screen as below

And API 35 indicate error button on the Android Device Manager.
Is Xamarin / Visual Studio 2022 not support for Android API 34 and 35?
Thank you.
